# ng-repeat on already existing element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on adding angular to my Rails app and I think I've hit a brick wall. I have a todos model, and a partial to render @todos. This gives me:

```
<h1>Todo 1</h1>
<h1>Todo 2</h1>
<h1>Todo 3</h1>
```

Just as expected. Now I want to be able to create todos with ajax, and render the new todo with angular. I tried doing `ng-repeat` on the todos parent div, but this just gives me:

```
<h1>Todo 1</h1>
<h1>Todo 2</h1>
<h1>Todo 3</h1>
<h1>Todo 1</h1>
<h1>Todo 2</h1>
<h1>Todo 3</h1>
<h1>Todo 1</h1>
<h1>Todo 2</h1>
<h1>Todo 3</h1>
```

Here's my partial:

```
<div ng-init="todos = <%= todos.to_json %>" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <h1 class="title"><%= link_to("{{ todo.title }}", todo) %></h1>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find a way to bind the existing elements to `$scope.todos` so that when I change it ng-repeat will reflect the changes in the DOM. Is there something I'm missing?

Disclaimer: I know that I can do this easily by separating the front and back ends and using an api to grab all my todos, but I'm trying to bring angular and rails as close as I can to accommodate non-javascript users. I don't want them to simply be presented with a blank page should they opt to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against outputting the JSON as a string in the ruby template.  Instead, a better practice would be to have a data API that returns the JSON; this way, your controller can call:

`$http.get('/my/api/', (data) => { $scope.todos = data; });`

And your template can just be:

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    ...
</div>
```

Essentially, we are making the distinction between the HTML view and the JSON data.  The server should return a general template that can be re-used with different data and the api should return data that can be used in different templates.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I was trying to tie the two as closely together as I could so any non-javascript users would lose very little in the area of usability. Your way would work just fine, but should a user disable javascript they'd be presented with a blank page. I'm hoping to avoid that and at least give them a basic list of items they can work with.

Comment: Added a disclaimer to better explain this weirdness. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You are trying to use `ng-repeat` which is an `angularJs` directive, which is a `JavaScript` framework. Disabling `JavaScript` will make `ng-repeat` to not work either.

Comment: Right, but in that event rails would still be able to render the data directly from the database.

Comment: How would rails know that the js didn't run?
I understand what you want to do, but I think there is a technical barrier to achieve it.

Comment: It wouldn't. The rails would run, spit out the html file containing the angular methods (`ng-repeat='todo in todos'`, etc), then those would be evaluated (or not). The goal is to avoid a blank page if JS is disabled, while working with the base rails-produced html to add functionality. I think I could achieve this by clearing the DOM with JS then re-rendering it with angular, but I'd rather not resort to that if I can avoid it.

Comment: I see. Maybe you'll want to look into isomorphism.  I'm not sure if Angular 1 supports it, but I think Angular 2 and React definitely do.
https://github.com/angular/universal
http://isomorphic.net/

Comment: Thanks! I searched 'rails isomorphism' and found this article that looks like it might get me on my way: https://medium.com/technically-speaking/isomorphic-reactjs-app-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1-server-side-rendering-8438bbb1ea1c#.mq6z1aiv4